# GlassFish server fails to start even after changing listener ports

Tags: java, glassfish

I use netbeans IDE 7.4 and Glassfish version-4.0  . I am so irritated with the error, "Glassfish server failed to start the HTTP and HTTPS listener ports are occupied."
I changed the domain.xml file credentials  like this

> ```
>  network-listener name="http-listener-1" port="8686" protocol="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"/>
> ```

```
  network-listener name="http-listener-2" port="8787" protocol="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"/>

  network-listener name="admin-listener" port="8888" protocol="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool" transport="tcp"/>
```

Still the problem persists. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to find the process that already use the ports.What is your operationg system ? netstat -a -b could help to find the process.

Comment: I used netstat and then put the port numbers. But the problem still persist should i close and restart netbeans after doing changes?

Comment: Hi the problem resolved. I closed and restarted Netbeans again. Thanks for showing interest in answering.

Comment: You must change all the port used by glassfish and are already use by a process. Can you post the full error message ?

Comment: Now new error is being displayed...
Error :E:\ServletPrograms\CurrencyConverterBean\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
Error line :        <nbdeploy clientModuleUri="${client.module.uri}" clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>